# tkinter проверка if состояния status у button

Tags: python, функции, tkinter, button, if

Возник такой вопрос. Есть функция, внутри которой перед выполнением должна происходить проверка с помощью **If** на **status button**. То есть, если кнопка активна: 'normal' или неактивна: 'disable'. Функция выглядит так:

```
def add():
    if Button_add_games['state'] == 'normal':
```

Вроде всё логично, если у кнопки статус такой, делаем дела. Однако, по неведомой мне причине, он почему-то пропускает это условие **If**.
Подскажите как можно исправить?

Допустим пример кода. Условие if не работает.

```
def add():
    if Button_add_games2['state'] == 'disable':
        label_Name = ttk.Label(app, text='Название')
        label_Name.place(x=10, y=90)

Button_add_games1 = ttk.Button(app, text='Внесение 1', state='normal', command=add)
Button_add_games1 .place(width=130, height=60, x=250, y=15)

Button_add_games2 = ttk.Button(app, text='Внесение 2', state='disable', command=add)
Button_add_games2.place(width=130, height=60, x=380, y=15)
```

Comment: единственно предположение по Вашему коду - это невызов функции add

Comment: Есть кнопка, как только на неё нажимает пользователь, она проверяет: какие кнопки Заблокированы, а какие Активны и уже с этими параметрами исполняет тот или иной код. То есть проверка условия должна быть внутри функции. Состояние кнопок прописано так: Button_add_games = ttk.Button(tab_add, text='Внесение', state='normal', command=add_games_1)

Comment: Создайте, пожалуйста, минимальный пример воспроизводящий проблему. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Сделал пример кода в основном сообщении

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если добавить `print(type(Button_add_games2['state']))`, то будет видно, что там лежит не строка, а объект типа `<class '_tkinter.Tcl_Obj'>`. Из-за этого условие и не выполняется - этот объект не равен строке `"disable"`.

Проверка будет срабатывать, если сконвертировать этот объект в строку:

```
def add():
    print(type(Button_add_games2['state']))  # <class '_tkinter.Tcl_Obj'>
    print(str(Button_add_games2['state']))  # disable
    if str(Button_add_games2['state']) == 'disable':
        label_Name = ttk.Label(app, text='Название')
        label_Name.place(x=10, y=90)
```

Comment: Вау! Я даже не знал, что причина у всего этого кроется с такой стороны. Спасибо больше за разъяснения. Исправлю и буду помнить об этом =)